# Does anyone go through the package flutter_sharing_intent? It doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, ios8-share-extension

Just went through the details of [flutter_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sharing_intent) and all fine on Android, but not working on iOS. Any clues?

Already followed the steps in setting up the environment in XCode but no luck. The main application  couldn't be launched with anything shared via ActionSheet menu on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like some typos on the package's site:

[image]

Erase this two lines:

```
<key>AppGroupId</key>
<string>$(CUSTOM_GROUP_ID)</string>
```

in ios/Runner/info.plist

Also the url scheme is different (ShareMedia- vs SharingMedia-) from what is shown in the code:

[image]

[image]

So change ShareMedia- to SharingMedia- in ios/Runner/info.plist

Hope it may help!

Comment: Updating from receive_sharing_intent to receive_sharing_intent_plus and this helped me a lot since the redirectToHostApp function is different between the two.